# Proxies with authentication working in Python but not in Node.js and C#

Tags: python, c#, node.js, authentication, proxy

Hello StackOverflow community,

**I'm encountering an issue with using proxies that require authentication in Node.js and C#, but not in Python.**

Here's the Python code that works fine:

```
import requests

proxy = {
    'http': 'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:8008',
    'https': 'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:8008'
}
response = requests.get('http://ip-api.com/json', proxies=proxy)
print(response.text)
```

However, when I try to use the same proxy in Node.js or C#, I'm not getting any response or I'm getting an exception. Here's the Node.js code I'm using:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

(async () => {
    const proxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent('http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:8008');
    const response = await fetch('http://ip-api.com/json', { agent: proxyAgent } );
    const html = await response.text();
    console.log(html);
})();
```

This code runs without any errors, but the response is empty.

And here's the C# code I'm using:

```
var proxy = new WebProxy
{
    Address = new Uri("http://HOST:8008"),
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
        userName: "USERNAME",
        password: "PASSWORD")
};

var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = proxy,
};

httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

var client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);

var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://ip-api.com/json");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This code results in the following exception: `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. (System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was closed by the remote host.)`

I've tried various solutions found on StackOverflow, such as changing the authentication format, adding additional headers, or changing the proxy settings, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after hours of tedious network debugging i've come up with a theory.

## Requirements for this scenario

1. When using a proxy *some* node http client package fails to handle HTTP version upgrade from `HTTP/1.1` to `HTTP/2` and remains on `HTTP/1.1`
2. The target server fails to serve the page on `HTTP/1.1`

## How to check if this is the case

### Step 1.

We are using `curl` to get the target site through a proxy and forcing `HTTP/2` protocol. This command should work flawlessly.

```bash
curl -v --http2 -x http://username:password@proxy:port https://target.site -O > /dev/null
```

*Notice in the logs:*

```
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
```

This means the server supports both protocols.

### Step 2.

We are doing the same as the previous step, however we are **forcing curl to use `HTTP/1.1`.** This command should fail (hang forever or timeout).

```bash
curl -v --http1.1 -x http://username:password@proxy:port https://target.site -O > /dev/null
```

## Fix in node

I encountered this problem using `axios@1.3.6` and turns out [they don't support `HTTP/2` at all.](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1175)

This is a **VERY LIMITED** `typescript` solution I've come up with. It connects to the proxy server, then tunnels over that connection to reach the target server.

```js
import * as net from 'net';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as http2 from 'node:http2';

/**
 * Gets a page through HTTP/2 via a given HTTP proxy by tunneling.
 *
 * LIMITATIONS:
 * - The proxy MUST USE basic auth
 * - WILL NOT follow redirects
 * - HTTPS only (WILL NOT fallback)
 * - HTTP/2 only (WILL NOT downgrade)
 * - Target site MUST USE port 443
 *
 * @param url The url to get
 * @param proxy The http proxy
 * @param headers (Optional) Object to sent as headers to target site
 */
export const http2GetViaProxy = (
  url: string,
  proxy: string,
  headers?: Record<string, string>
): Promise<string> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const parsedProxy = new URL(proxy);
    const parsedUrl = new URL(url);

    http
      .request({
        host: parsedProxy.hostname,
        port: parsedProxy.port,
        method: 'CONNECT',
        path: `${parsedUrl.hostname}:443`, // WARNING: https only
        headers: {
          'Proxy-Authorization':
            'Basic ' +
            Buffer.from(
              parsedProxy.username + ':' + parsedProxy.password
            ).toString('base64'),
          Host: parsedUrl.hostname,
        },
      })
      .on('connect', (res: http.IncomingMessage, socket: net.Socket) => {
        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
          throw new Error(`Cannot connect to proxy: ${res.statusCode}`);
        }

        let data = '';

        const client = http2
          .connect('https://' + parsedUrl.hostname, { socket }) // WARNING: https only
          .on('error', reject);

        client
          .request({
            ':path': parsedUrl.pathname,
            ...headers,
          })
          .setEncoding('utf8')
          .on('data', (chunk: string) => {
            data += chunk;
          })
          .on('end', () => {
            client.close();
            resolve(data);
          })
          .end();
      })
      .end();
  });
```

The solution above is based on merging various answers I found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840291/how-do-you-send-http-2-requests-via-a-proxy-using-node-js)